# How to make a small page using Bootstrap 4 responsive?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, bootstrap-4

I've coded a small page using Bootstrap 4 as a framework, but it's not responsive.

Here is my html:

```
<div class="container h-100 d-flex flex-column" id="container">
      <div class="row align-items-start" id="header">
          <div class="col">
            header
          </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row h-100" id="main">
          <div class="col">
            <p></p>
          </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row align-items-end" id="footer">
          <div class="col">
            footer
          </div>
      </div>

   </div>
```

And here is my css

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

#container {
  background-color: rgb(255, 219, 164);
}

#header, #footer {
  background-color: rgb(33, 202, 202);
}
```

When I type a long paragraph inside the `<p>` element it goes it a bad way and I can't solve that. How can I make it full responsive?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "not responsive" by providing more information. Have you provided the meta tag named "viewport" to begin with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better use `min-vh-100` instead of `h-100` (or `vh-100`) so that you define a min-height and in case you have a lot of content you will get a scroll.

```css
#container {
  background-color: rgb(255, 219, 164);
}

#header,
#footer {
  background-color: rgb(33, 202, 202);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container min-vh-100 d-flex flex-column" id="container">
  <div class="row align-items-start" id="header">
    <div class="col">
      header
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row flex-grow-1" id="main">
    <div class="col">
      <p>text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row align-items-end" id="footer">
    <div class="col">
      footer
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Normally, if it's not responsive you've not imported the required JavaScript. Follow the Quick Start page on the [official documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/) and that it has been put in the correct place of your project (the `</body>`). Use a template to start with for better understanting

I can't yet comment because of my rep but adding more code (such as your `</body>` and `<head>` information will give the the community more understanding on what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate the issue that you did mention above. I couldn't replicate it. Also take a look at the files included in  tag. Please take a look at this codepen attached [Codepen](https://codepen.io/ruphaa/pen/ZwEXQN?editors=1100).
`

```
  </div>

  <div class="row h-100" id="main">
      <div class="col">
        <p>Responsive web design is about creating web sites which automatically adjust themselves to look good on all devices, from small phones to large desktops.Responsive web design is about creating web sites which automatically adjust themselves to look good on all devices, from small phones to large desktops.Responsive web design is about creating web sites which automatically adjust themselves to look good on all devices, from small phones to large desktops.</p>
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row align-items-end" id="footer">
      <div class="col">
        footer
      </div>
  </div>
```

`