# How to make textarea element fill all the height using bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

How to make textarea element fill all the height between the header and footer without getting a scroll bar using bootstrap 4?
here is my html code:

```css
#container {
    background-color: rgb(253, 248, 177);
}

#title {
    color: white;
    padding-top: 7px; 
}

#cancel, #submit {
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
}

#add {
    font-size: 20px; 
}

#delete, #cancel, #submit {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container min-vh-100 d-flex flex-column" id="container">

  <!-- header -->
  <div class="row align-items-start bg-info" id="header">
    <div class="col text-center">
      <button type="button" class="btn" id="cancel">&#10007;</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col text-center">
      <h4 id="title">Notebook</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col text-center">
      <button type="button" class="btn" id="submit">&#10004;</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <br />
  <!-- main -->
  <div class="row flex-grow-1">
    <div class="col" id="main">
      <textarea class="form-control textarea" placeholder="write note" id="note"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- footer -->
  <div class="row align-items-end" id="footer">
    <div class="col d-flex justify-content-start" style="padding: 10px; padding-left: 25px;">
      <button id="add" class="btn btn-info rounded-circle">
        <h4 style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">&#x2b;</h4>
      </button>
      <button id="delete" class="btn btn-info rounded-circle">&#128465;</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

can anyone tell me how to do that, i want it to be responsive so i don't want to set specific number of rows to the textarea element.

Comment: You are using a code provided for you in a previous question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54304839/how-to-make-a-small-page-using-bootstrap-4-responsive) and you did the same with another question, etc ... If some answers solve your issue you should accept them and not only take the code to ask another question based on it. At least we know that this is what you want.

Comment: @TemaniAfif I know i've asked a simillar question, but my problem now is a little bit different, i want the text area element to fill all the place between header and footer, when i add the ```min-vh-100``` to the textarea element it fill the place but i've to scroll down to reach the footer, i want the textarea element to fill the place and all the element to be shown on the screen without need to scroll.

Comment: you can ask as many question as you want, but it seems each time you take code provided for you from an old question to use it in the new one. You should then accept those answers to remove the question for the unanswered queue. Don't cumulate a lot of question without *closing* old ones by accepting answers (your aren't obliged, but it's a good practise)

Comment: @TemaniAfif I'm new in stackoverflow and i don't know how to close the old questions ..

Comment: simply accept the answers that solves your issues. read this : https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers (again you aren't obliged)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add `h-100` to the textarea since its parent div has already `flex-grow-1` so it's already filling all the remaining space:

```css
#container {
    background-color: rgb(253, 248, 177);
}

#title {
    color: white;
    padding-top: 7px; 
}

#cancel, #submit {
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
}

#add {
    font-size: 20px; 
}

#delete, #cancel, #submit {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >
<div class="container min-vh-100 d-flex flex-column" id="container">

      <!-- header -->
      <div class="row align-items-start bg-info" id="header">
        <div class="col text-center">
            <button type="button" class="btn" id="cancel">&#10007;</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col text-center">
          <h4 id="title">Notebook</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col text-center">
            <button type="button" class="btn" id="submit">&#10004;</button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <br />
      <!-- main -->
      <div class="row flex-grow-1">
        <div class="col" id="main">
            <textarea class="form-control textarea h-100"  placeholder="write note" id="note"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- footer -->
      <div class="row align-items-end" id="footer">
        <div class="col d-flex justify-content-start" style="padding: 10px; padding-left: 25px;">
          <button id="add" class="btn btn-info rounded-circle"><h4 style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">&#x2b;</h4></button>
          <button id="delete" class="btn btn-info rounded-circle">&#128465;</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative answer, Instead of `Text Area` you can use `<div contenteditable="true" > </div>`. For the place holder I have achieved the same using CSS.

```css
#container {
    background-color: rgb(253, 248, 177);
}

#title {
    color: white;
    padding-top: 7px; 
}

#cancel, #submit {
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
}

#add {
    font-size: 20px; 
}

#delete, #cancel, #submit {
    display: none;
}

div[data-placeholder]:not(:focus):not([data-div-placeholder-content]):before {

    content: attr(data-placeholder);

    float: left;

    margin-left: 2px;

    color: #b3b3b3;

}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container min-vh-100 d-flex flex-column" id="container">

      <!-- header -->
      <div class="row align-items-start bg-info" id="header">
        <div class="col text-center">
            <button type="button" class="btn" id="cancel">&#10007;</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col text-center">
          <h4 id="title">Notebook</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col text-center">
            <button type="button" class="btn" id="submit">&#10004;</button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <br />
      <!-- main -->
      <div class="row flex-grow-1">
        <div class="col" id="main">
            <div contenteditable="true"  class="form-control textarea"  data-placeholder="Write note!" id="note"></div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- footer -->
      <div class="row align-items-end" id="footer">
        <div class="col d-flex justify-content-start" style="padding: 10px; padding-left: 25px;">
          <button id="add" class="btn btn-info rounded-circle"><h4 style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">&#x2b;</h4></button>
          <button id="delete" class="btn btn-info rounded-circle">&#128465;</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
```